# Просмотр отчётов в Allure сгруппированные по suites

Tags: java, testng, allure

Есть тесты, с кучей разных сюитов. Часто сюиты запускаются по отдельности. Есть ли какая то возможность просмотреть историю запусков для конкретных сюитов?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, ты спрашиваешь про это, нужно перейти в сьютс в левом блоке потом провалиться в нужный сьют и в правом блоке переключиться на ретрайс(отмечен красным прямоугольником на картинке)
[image: примерное изображение где это находится]

Comment: добавьте к картинке текстовое описание, пожалуйста